# How can I show the time selector when clicking anywhere in a time input?

Tags: html

How can I make input show menu  when clicked? It is only showing when the icon is clicked.

```html
<input id="appt-time" type="time" name="appt-time" value="13:30">
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this UI is different across browsers.

Comment: You can use plugins/library like this:https://codepen.io/Lance-Jernigan/pen/jARLLO

Comment: Then of course you'd want to delete the comment you've duplicated. :)

Comment: Fair point - done.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're asking to change default behaviour that is up to the browser to implement (in standard HTML). If you want more control, you'll have to use a custom picker - either by writing it yourself or via a framework like Bootstrap. However, that's probably overkill just for one widget.

Given that the behaviour depends on the browser, it's also worth asking yourself whether you really need to change what the user will expect given how their browser usually does things - or whether you're doing it just because it's how you like to use the widget.